# Regex extract list of names

Tags: regex

I have almost complete regex, but does not capture "director Nicolas Winding Ref", appreciate any help

```
: Actor Keanu Reeves attends

: Actors Keanu Reeves, Alessandro Nivola, Christina Hendricks, Bella Heathcote, Elle Fanning and director Nicolas Winding Refn attend

: Actresses Bella Heathcote, Elle Fanning and Christina Hendricks attend
```

regex:

```
: {1}([A-Za-z\. \-,]*?) (?!and)[a-z]
```

https://www.debuggex.com/r/i8yEYRXVhlf9TzQL

Comment: any verbs https://www.debuggex.com/r/B2FE8cgB3l220Bab

Comment: : ([A-Z][\w\.\-\']*(?: [A-Z][\w\.\-\']*)*(?:, [A-Z][\w\.\-\']*(?: [A-Z][\w\.\-\']*)*)*)(?: and(?: [a-z\.']+)? ([A-Z][\w\.\-\']*(?: [A-Z][\w\.\-\']*)*))?

Comment: finished : ([A-Z][\w\.\-\']*(?: [A-Z][\w\.\-\']*)*(?:, [\w\.\-\']*(?: [A-Z][\w\.\-\']*)*)*)(?: and(?: [a-z]+)? ([A-Z][\w\.\-\']*(?: [A-Z][\w\.\-\']*)*))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you want something like this,

```
: ([A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*(?:, [A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*)*)(?: and(?: \w+)? ([A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*))?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zL9xT0/3)

Comment: attend not a single verb there can be hundreds of verbs, so I wrote [a-z]

Comment: http://www.gettyimages.com/license/531578152
http://www.gettyimages.com/license/540152876

Comment: Talk about how to get only list of names with positions (director, actor, etc)

Comment: I tried make it through python nltk, but to name detect is spend ~350ms, so I can make it through regex :)

Comment: Yes it will work only specific words, the point is not to make reference to specific words :) Thank you, I'm going to try next.

Comment: CANNES, FRANCE - MAY 15: Louise Grinbert, Sadek, director Rachid Djaidani, Gerard Depardieu, producer Anne-Dominique Toussaint and guest attend 'Tour de France'

not get only this (please see the main post comments)